# how to modify the type mapping in elasticsearch to another type

Tags: elasticsearch

The thing is that I already defined a field "myvalue" as INTEGER. Now I think was a mistake and I want to store in the same field an string, so I want to change it, without loosing data, to STRING. is there any way of making it?, or I need to re-create the index and re-index the whole data?

I already tried running:

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "myvalue": {
                           "type":"string"
}
    }
}
```

But if I get the mapping again from the server still appear as Integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not any way to change the mapping on a core field type for existing data. You will need to re-create the index with the `myvalue` field defined as a string and re-index your data.